# How to control the scroll in horizontal listview?

Tags: java, android

![enter image description here][1]i have the HorizontalListView.when I swipe the list items. I need only one list item to be displayed on the screen. And for a one swipe i need one list item to be scrolled.

Could anyone pls help me for this

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iugTg.png`enter code here`

Answer (score 0):

If you use this HorizontalListView implementation (https://github.com/dinocore1/DevsmartLib-Android/blob/master/devsmartlib/src/com/devsmart/android/ui/HorizontalListView.java) then you can use `scrollTo` method

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your requirements correctly, that is, full-width items and sweep to move to next/previous full-width item, you should use e.g. [`ViewPager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html) instead of `HorizontalListView`.